# KML Locations file - displays correctly in GoogleEarth, but not in OpenLayers2 on a GoogleMap Base Layer

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, openlayers, kml

I have a set of places saved from GoogleEarth as a KML file. I am trying to get the same locations to display on a simple OpenLayer2 map using the following Js code :

```
var map;

function init() {
    var bounds = new OpenLayers.Bounds();
    bounds.extend( new OpenLayers.LonLat(0.2, 52.3).transform('EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'));
    bounds.extend( new OpenLayers.LonLat(1.9, 51.5).transform('EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'));

    map = new OpenLayers.Map('map', {
        projection: 'EPSG:3857',
        layers: [
            new OpenLayers.Layer.Google(
                "Google Streets", // the default
                { numZoomLevels: null, minZoomLevel: 1, maxZoomLevel: 16 }
        ),
    ],
    controls: [ new OpenLayers.Control.Navigation(),
                new OpenLayers.Control.PanZoomBar(),
    ],
    center: new OpenLayers.LonLat( 1.0, 52.1)
        // Google.v3 uses web mercator as projection, so we have to
        // transform our coordinates
        .transform('EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'),
        restrictedExtent: bounds,
        zoom: 9,
    });

var layer =  new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("KML", {
        animationEnabled: true,
        projection: map.displayProjection,
        strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.Fixed()],
        protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.HTTP({
            url: "/static/OL3Example/kml/locations.kml",
            format: new OpenLayers.Format.KML({
                extractStyles: true,
                extractAttributes: true
            })
        })
    }) ;
map.addLayer(layer);

map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.LayerSwitcher());
}
```

The Restricted Extends make the map display just SUffolk, Uk, and all but 4 of the locations are in Suffolk (so should be on the map). Looking at the KML data I can confirm that the locations in the KML are correct Decimal Lon/Lat.

When I remove the Restricted Extent from the map - I can pan around the world, and I can then see a cluster of Icons at 0 Lon, 0 Lat.

I have looked at the documentation - and a number of stackoverflow related questions : for instance [OpenLayers not displaying kml layer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16589573/openlayers-not-displaying-kml-layer), but none have answered the question.

I have used Firebug to investigate the map object and it's layers - and I can confirm that the layer is visible - and is drawn, and there are no unrenderedFeatures on the layer - suggesting that the layer is loading fine - and it is a projection thing - though what is confusing.

Comment: The same thing happens with Google maps 3 - the 2 API isn't turned off - since i can see the map (with place names, roads etc)... although using the 3 API is of course the better way to go long term of course.

Comment: I have just double checked this is the Google Map v3 interface - the tag is wrong !